# Why does this struct member need two lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have the following `struct`:

```
struct PeekableRead<'a, R: Read> {
    reader: &'a mut R,
    peeked_octet: Option<u8>,
}
```

Which `rustc` does not like:

```
…:27:1: 30:2 error: the parameter type `R` may not live long enough [E0309]
…:27 struct PeekableRead<'a, R: Read> {
…:28    reader: &'a mut R,
…:29    peeked_octet: Option<u8>,
…:30 }
…:27:1: 30:2 help: run `rustc --explain E0309` to see a detailed explanation
…:27:1: 30:2 help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `R: 'a`...
…:27:1: 30:2 note: ...so that the reference type `&'a mut R` does not outlive the data it points at
…:27 struct PeekableRead<'a, R: Read> {
…:28    reader: &'a mut R,
…:29    peeked_octet: Option<u8>,
…:30 }
```

If I add the lifetime to `R`, as in, `R: Read + 'a`, it works. But *why*? Doesn't the `'a` on the reference specify the lifetime? Must not `reader: &'a mut R`, in a `struct PeekableRead<'a>` live as long as the struct itself, and thus, "long enough"?

Oddly, I seem to need *both*; if I add `'a` to `R` and remove it from the reference, I still get `error: missing lifetime specifier`. The only way I get a successful compilation is with both, but to me, they appear to specify the same thing redundantly.

(Also, why does `rustc` output the `struct` twice in the output? The second one looks like a suggestion of what to do, but appears to be exactly the same as what I have…)

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't the 'a on the reference specify the lifetime?

It specifies the lifetime of *the reference*, but not the lifetime of the value being pointed to. Which explains your observation that

> if I add 'a to R and remove it from the reference, I still get error: missing lifetime specifier.

For the struct to be valid we need both: the value being pointed to must still be alive, and so must the reference. (Although logically, the first condition is implied by the second, since a reference can never outlive the value it points to.).

Comment: You can consider `struct PeekableRead<'a, R: 'a + Read>` the externally visible API for the struct, while the fields are implementation details. Yet this motivation is not a general rule, because we can think of some properties of the struct that are not explicitly spelled out like this (variance of each generic parameter and auto traits).

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime parameter on a reference designates the lifetime of the referent (i.e. the object the reference points to). That object may be a reference, or a complex object that contains one or more references. However, when you use a trait, the lifetime of the objects behind those references are somewhat hidden (the trait itself doesn't know about those lifetimes); lifetime bounds are what lets the compiler reason correctly about those lifetimes.

When you use a generic type behind a reference, you need to add a bound to ensure that instances of that type don't contain references that are shorter than the reference to that those instances. Bounds are not implicitly added just based on how you use types: the bounds should not change based on the details of what fields are in the struct and what type you define them to be.

For example, the type `&'f File` (for each `'f`) implements `Read`. We can instantiate `PeekableRead` with that type: this gives us a `PeekableRead<&'f File>`. `PeekableRead<&'f File>` stores a mutable reference to a `&'f File`, so the concrete type of the `reader` field is `&'a mut &'f File`. In order for such a reference to be valid, `'a` must be shorter or equal to `'f`. If `'f` was shorter than `'a`, then you could replace the `&'f File` with one that would be dropped before the reference is dropped, leading to a dangling pointer. When you add the `'a` bound to `R` (i.e. when you write `R: Read + 'a`), you say "*instances of `R` must outlive `'a`*" (i.e. `R` may not contain references shorter than `'a`).